# Javascript -- Manipulating values in multidimensional array while iterating

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm given a matrix, and for every index that has a value of 0, I have to make the index directly below it to 0 as well.

```
for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length;j++) {
        //figure out what rooms not 0
        if(matrix[i][j] !== 0) {
            goodRooms.push(matrix[i][j])             
        } else {
            matrix[i + 1][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the

> `TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

At the `else` statement, and i'm not sure why.

Comment: Because `matrix[i+1]` is `undefined` and `j =0`, then you try to set the property (undefined)[0] to an undefined object/array  `matrix[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `else` to

```
else if(i < matrix.length - 1)
```

Otherwise if you are on the last row and the value is `0`, you'll be accessing the next row which doesn't exist.

The final code should look like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j] !== 0) {
            goodRooms.push(matrix[i][j]);
        } else if(i < matrix.length - 1) {
            matrix[i + 1][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This will change the next row before the loop reaches that row. So if the first row contains a 0 value, the second row will be changed before the loop accesses it and thus when the loop reaches it the value will already be 0 and so the whole column will recursively be set to 0.

Comment: I tried it and it set the whole matrix to [[0]], it isn't setting the value at index below to 0

Comment: I figured it out.. Instead of using else if, I rearranged the code to have the first if check ```if (i < matrix.length -1 && matrix[i][j] === 0)```

Comment: @fev3r Read the **note** part. If that is not your desired result then please tell me how exactly do you want to handle that case?

Comment: @fev3r The `&& matrix[i][j] === 0` is redundant. It is already implied by the `else if` itself

Comment: Ah okay, I see now. It was an issue with a reduce function that I was working on below the code.

Comment: @fev3r is the issue mentioned in the **note** part not a problem?

Comment: No, I don't believe it is a problem, but it only becomes an issue when the matrix passed has only 1 value or 1 row. There are some edge cases where this doesn't work when I feel it should because the logic is correct.